# formvalidation only work once

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

i'm using [this plugin](http://formvalidation.io/) to validate my form. when i first click on submit the plugin works but if i have errors, fix them and click again, the plugin will always go to 'onError' (even if the form is ok).

```
$('#save_edit_student').on('click', function(event){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('button_disabled')){
     $('#edit_student_form').formValidation('validate');
  }
  event.preventDefault();
 });

$('#edit_student_form').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            autoFocus : true,
            fields: {
                form_student_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please enter student\'s first name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                form_student_lastname: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please enter student\'s last name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                username: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                             message: 'Please enter a username.'
                         },
                        remote: {
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'validator.php',
                            message: 'That username is already taken.',
                            delay: 500
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            onError: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#save_edit_student').removeClass('button-disabled');
            },
            onSuccess: function(e) {
                some on success code
            }
        });
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a link to the plugin API instead of just the main page.. http://formvalidation.io/api/

Comment: Have you tried `$('#edit_student_form').formValidation('resetForm');`  before calling `$('#edit_student_form').formValidation('validate');` ? http://formvalidation.io/api/#reset-form

Comment: Thanks @MjrKusanagi ! that works. but i'm not sure why do i need to add it.. the plugin supposed to it alone

Comment: I've never heard of the plugin - I just guessed that from reading the API page. But you are right, their documentation isn't really clear about that. Maybe it's not normally needed, but your particular configuration happens to be non-standard. If you feel strongly that it should be standard, you should submit a feature request so they can improve their plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and calling the `resetForm()` method before the form is validated works. The difference in my case was that the actual problem with re-validating the form elements affected ONLY checboxes and radio input groups. The form re-validation worked just fine with text, textarea and select inputs. Is this potentially a bug with the formvalidation.io?

Comment: i read a little and it seems that my issue is different one... i didn't mentioned this but my form is on bootstrap modal and i need to act different when i'm trying to validate a form in modal. still not working for me